# In emacs, how do I get make the pdflatex output on a successful compilation?

Tags: emacs, pdflatex

After hitting C-c RET and compiling my .tex file, I would like the *tex-shell* buffer to close if the compilation was successful. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In my `.emacs` I have the following code:

```
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
         (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %t" 'TeX-master-file)
         master-file)
    (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
        (TeX-next-error t)
      (minibuffer-message "latexmk done"))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-0") #'run-latexmk))
      )
```

This binds `C-0` to the defined function `run-latexmk` which in turn saves all the files of the current document (based on the notion of `master` file) and then runs `latexmk`. If the compilation was successful then the compilation window closes. You can easily(?) change this code to your needs.

This answer is based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885853/emacs-latexmk-function-throws-me-into-an-empty-buffer) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587287/how-do-i-bind-latexmk-to-one-key-in-emacs-and-have-it-show-errors-if-there-are-a).